# How to configure https nginx configuration for multiple running port in ubuntu server

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-ingress, nginx-location

Facing a unique type of issue for hosting multiple port (5000, 5001) in ubuntu server. I am using Nginx to configure two subdomains in the directory "/etc/nginx/site-availabe" and I delink default configuration. but the main issue is when listen to port ":80" is working fine for both subdomain but when configured for both SSL cert file and listen to 443 is only pointing to port 5000 for both subdomain, not for 5001 port. I will share my config file if I have any config problem.

This setting for 5001 port

```
server {
        listen  80;
        server_name lenderapp.xxx.in;
        return 301 https://lenderapp.xxx.in$request_uri;
       # rewrite ^(.*) https://lenderapp.xxx.in$1 permanent;
    }
server {
        listen  443;
        ssl on;
        server_name     www.lenderapp.xxx.in;
        #root   /home/dmin/OProjects/lender_demo;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error_lenderapp.log error;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/lenderapp_access.log;
        ssl_certificate /home/admin/OProjects/ssl_cert/lender_cert/ssl_cert.cert;
        ssl_certificate_key     /home/admin/OProjects/ssl_cert/lender_cert/ssl_cert_key.key;
        location /{
                        proxy_pass  http://0.0.0.0:5001;
                        root    /home/admin/OProjects/lender_demo;
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

Now 2nd setting for port 5000

```
server {
        listen  80;
        server_name bcadmin.xxx.in;
        return 301 https://bcadmin.xxx.in$request_uri;
        #rewrite ^(.*) https://bcadmin.xxx.in$1 permanent;
    }
server {
        listen  443     ssl     http2;
        server_name     www.bcadmin.tradefi.in;
        root    /home/admin/OProjects/admin_console;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/lenderapp.log error;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/lenderapp_access.log;
        ssl_certificate /home/admin/OProjects/ssl_cert/ssl_cert.cert;
        ssl_certificate_key     /home/admin/OProjects/ssl_cert/ssl_cert_key.key;
        location /{
                        proxy_pass  'http://0.0.0.0:5000';
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

Please help me guys... I need help badly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot see a real error in you config on first glance. But using `0.0.0.0` as target IP - this IP is kind of "any IP". You should stick to `127.0.0.1` for local redirects. Also `ssl on` is deprecated since 06/2018...

I would recommend to split your config into several files to keep a better overview. It will make the config more readable and will really help you on daily routines (and enhancements).

For your config my approach would be the following. I am using this config for > 35 domains without problems on one of my servers. It will not *just work*, but also give you an A+ rating on [SSLtest](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/). This config adopts your log- and cert file names - that in my opinion are not optimal ;)

#### Main Config

```
# This block redirect any :80 traffic to its https counterpart.
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server; # <-- ipv6
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2; # <-- ipv6
    server_name www.lenderapp.xxx.in;

    error_log           /var/log/nginx/error_lenderapp.log error;
    access_log          /var/log/nginx/lenderapp_access.log;
    include             params/ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /home/admin/OProjects/ssl_cert/lender_cert/ssl_cert.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/admin/OProjects/ssl_cert/lender_cert/ssl_cert_key.key;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
        include params/proxy_full;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2; # <-- ipv6
    server_name www.bcadmin.tradefi.in;

    error_log           /var/log/nginx/lenderapp.log error;
    access_log          /var/log/nginx/lenderapp_access.log;
    include             params/ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /home/admin/OProjects/ssl_cert/ssl_cert.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/admin/OProjects/ssl_cert/ssl_cert_key.key;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        include params/proxy_full;
    }
}
```

#### `params/ssl` (for my `/etc/nginx/params/proxy_full`)

**Caution**: You'll need a `dhparam` file inside `params` to make it work. Use `openssl dhparam -out /etc/nginx/params/dhparam.pem 4096` to create one if not existent.

```
ssl_session_timeout         10m;
ssl_session_cache           shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_protocols               TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers                 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
ssl_dhparam                 params/dhparam.pem;
ssl_ecdh_curve              secp384r1;
ssl_session_tickets         off;
ssl_stapling                on;
ssl_stapling_verify         on;
resolver                    8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;
resolver_timeout            5s;
```

#### `params/proxy_full` (for my `/etc/nginx/params/proxy_full`)

```
add_header          X-Upstream $upstream_addr;
proxy_http_version  1.1;
proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```